# how to make custom viewPager in android

Tags: android

Creating Custom Layout in viewPager. i want to swape the page using view pager but problem here while creating XML. i want to fix top bar and bottom task bar and also want to swape page between fix top bar and fix task bar. kindly help me  [image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0):

Use this kind of layout. change this based on your need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/topBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topBar" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```